# shared_ptr use_count() return 0 after assignment operator (=)

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

Im new to `shared_ptr` and can't wrap my around this,

I want to store `shared_ptr` in custom `struct`.

```
struct ThreadSafeQMsg
{
    ThreadSafeQMsg(shared_ptr<ptree> control, shared_ptr<uint32_t> data=0, int data_size=0) {
        data_size = data_size; 
        data = data;
        control = control;
    }
    size_t data_size;
    shared_ptr<ptree> control;
    shared_ptr<uint32_t> data;
};

    ThreadSafeQMsg* tmsg = new ThreadSafeQMsg(control,spData, data_size);
    PRINT_LOG("message with data[" << std::dec << tmsg->data_size << ",ref: " << std::dec << tmsg->data.use_count() 
                                 << "] & control[ref: " << std::dec << tmsg->control.use_count() << "]");
```

before assignment I see the that the ref count is 1
when checking after assignment I get:

```
message with data[140737018606128,ref: 0] & control[ref: 0]
```

what am I missing here?

Comment: Though it's not required, for safety, it's better to name constructor parameters differently than member variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside the constructor, the names of parameters *hide* the names of data members; so these assignments like `data_size = data_size;` are just assigning the parameters to themselves and have nothing to do with the data members, which are kept default-initialized.

You can initialize them in member initializer list as

```
ThreadSafeQMsg(shared_ptr<ptree> control, shared_ptr<uint32_t> data=0, int data_size=0) 
  : data_size(data_size), 
    control(control), 
    data(data) {
}
```

Or if you want to stick to assignment (but applying member initializer list is better in general).

```
ThreadSafeQMsg(shared_ptr<ptree> control, shared_ptr<uint32_t> data=0, int data_size=0) {
    this->data_size = data_size; 
    this->data = data;
    this->control = control;
}
```

Comment: Or avoid `this->` but instead prefix or suffix something, like `m_data_size`, but then we're into risky debate territory :-)

Comment: @underscore_d Yes, it's quite opinion-based. :)